# Crank Compatibility for my Orbea Hydro 2012

Tags: bottom-bracket, sram

I have received as a gift a set of SRAM bb30 cranks. I would like to know if they fit my 1012 Orbea Hydro and if can I use SRAM Alloy GXP Bottom Bracket to fit it all together.

Comment: Which orbea? (for those like me who didn't know, orbea is a bicycle manufacturer). This a very specific question, and it may come down to "try it and see". As well, why do you want to change the cranks? Is it just that you were given them? To me, the first question would be "what benefit do the other cranks offer?", followed by "is it worth the hassle of changing?"

Comment: Still not clear which Orbea bike this is -- afaik, hydro is just their model name for anything aluminum. With that, all we can refer to is something like: www.bikeradar.com/us/gear/article/complete-guide-to-bottom-brackets-36660/

Comment: GPX bottom bracket is for a 24mm crank spindle, BB30 uses a 30mm crank spindle these are not interchangeable and require frames be created explicitly for each standard.

Comment: The headline could be more descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a GXP bottom bracket to "fit it all together".

BB30 cranks do not fit in a GXP bottom bracket. A GXP crank *can* be made to fit a BB30 bottom bracket with an adapter, like one from Praxis.

If your Orbea is a GXP standard (24mm) the cranks are no good to you as they will not fit.  If it's a BB30 they will work without the need for any type of GXP bottom bracket.

Comment: All this info is straightforward and correct.  Should not be down voted.